# My welcome-file is returning an empty page in Open Liberty

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

On Open Liberty 21.0.0.6., instead of presenting my welcome JSF page, my browser returns empty content when I point it to `http://<host>:<port>/<ctxRoot>`,

#### web.xml

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">

  <display-name>MyJSF</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

   <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and a feature set of:

#### server.xml

```xml
<server>
  <featureManager>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.1</feature>
    <feature>cdi-2.0</feature>
    <feature>jpa-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.3</feature>
    <feature>jsf-2.3</feature>
    <feature>mpHealth-3.0</feature>
  </featureManager>
```

#### ADDITIONAL INFO

I also have some other stuff in my app like JPA and JAX-RS.

Answer (score 3):

### ROOT CAUSE - JAX-RS application with "/" application path

In my case the problem is that I had a JAX-RS Application configured to use:  `@ApplicationPath("/")` which was colliding with my goal of having the "/" application path serve up the welcome-file.

#### SOLUTION

Move the JAX-RS app to its own path within the WAR, e.g:

```java
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class TestApp extends Application { }
```

#### THOUGHTS

This was easy to stumble into by taking an existing simple JAX-RS app using "/" as the app path, and then adding JSF to it.  Then I thought I was having trouble with the JSF implementation.